# Can a hacker recover deleted files from my mobile drive?

Tags: malware, data-recovery

I deleted some files from my phone (android 5). Can a hacker recover my files?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12503/165253 and https://security.stackexchange.com/q/110734/165253

Comment: "Hacker"? Do you mean remotely? Do you mean if someone gets access to your phone? Where did you store these videos?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the `maleware` tag?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.

Thought it wouldn't take a "hacker" ... just anyone with knowledge of how to recover deleted files from a file system.  Most apple `geniuses` or Best Buy `Geek Squad` members could do this in there free time if they wanted to.

- If you encrypted your phone's hard drive it will be much harder.
- If your files are on a non-encrypted SD card ... it will be trivially easy.
- If you mean a rogue app doing this remotely ... it depends on if it has `root` or an exploit that can give it `root`